# Converting .mp3 files into .mid files using lstm autoencoder

Tags: python, numpy, audio, midi

I'll start with a little intro - just for letting you know the backgroud of my thoughts :)

I'm learning about MIR and I want to use deep learning to manipulate midi files.
My idea includes working with recording data - so it's have to be mp3/wav input data.

After a lot of researcing and thinking, I think i'm going to build my neural network based on midi input and output.

ok..so..let's move forward to the problem:
I need to convert mp3 files into midi files.

What I (with a lot of help from friends :D) thought about, is to use LSTM autoencoder for sequence to sequence learning, 
The nn will get an mp3 input and midi output, after some iterations it should find the best features to do the convertion and with that model I would convert the sound files recorded from my program - so I could learn from thier midi files.

The problem with that solution (for me) is to sync between the numpy arrays of each media file.

I need to give the net the same timestamp of each media so it could learn the convertion between them.

Sorry for not telling, I'm using python and keras over theano platform.

A lot of thanks for the helpers!! 
Have a great day! :)

Comment: You'd better add some implementation as less as possible.

Comment: Right now all I have is using librosa libary to get the numpy array of the sound data. All the rest is curently theoreticly..